# Node.js "Server listening on port 3000", but I can't view it in browser?

Tags: node.js, server, cloud

I am trying to get a simple node app running. It works fine on my localhost, but as soon as I am trying to get it to run on my cloud server, it doesn't work. When I do "node app.js" in the right path I get my console.log `Express server started on port %s', server.address().port` and it also says that it is port 3000(Express server started on port 3000). When I change the `server.listen` to another port, it displays the right port.

Now when I try to get it running via my domain or via my ip(for example xx.xxx.xx.xx:3000) or my domain (my-domain.com:3000) in both cases it doesn't work. I think I don't quite get the concept and I tried to search for a billion different things, but I can't find the solution to my problem. Could someone tell me, if I need to setup something else, too?

Comment: Are you sure your provider is having installed node.js?

Comment: I installed it myself... node -v also shows v0.12, node app.js works, etc.

Comment: I think both answers below are correct. Can you try to telnet into your server in port 3000? `$ telnet <server ip> 3000`

Comment: port 80 works flawlessly, port 3000 fails(stuck on "trying")...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Propably your cloud hosting provider doesn't have the port open for access. Try port 80 which is usually open.

Comment: Hey, thank you. Port 80 shows "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page", even when I add it in the app

Comment: Stop apache first, otherwise it is running on port 80 as shown.

Comment: Holy COW! It works! How can I get this running on other ports?

Comment: @FrederikWitte contact your cloud hosting provider regarding opening more ports, making them reachable from outside the server.

Answer (score 4):

It's likely that your code is working but that your server is not configured to allow access to port 3000.

To confirm You could try changing your app to Port 80 which is a default and most likely enabled.

Search your host documentation for 'enabling or opening ports'

Comment: Hey, thank. Port 80 shows "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page", even when I add it in the app

Comment: @Frederik Witte, you'd need to stop apache running first, then launch your Node App. They cannot both own the same port. - sudo systemctl stop apache2.service

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue. After banging my head a lot, checking all opened/used ports and trying various other stuff, I finally found out that since I was using AWS, I had to actually enable that port through Security Group section for my AWS EC2 instance.

I had to add a **Custom TCP Rule** in Security Group section for port number 3000 which I wanted to use for NodeJS server after which NodeJS server started responding on port 3000.

Comment: same thing applied for aws lightsail

Answer (score 0):

I was the facing same issue for on-premises Windows Server 2016.

My problem was Windows Firewall was blocking the access to port 3000.

Check if your firewall is blocking access to port 3000, you can follow these steps:

Open the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security console.

1. In the left pane, expand Inbound Rules. In the right pane, search
   for a rule that allows connections to port 3000.
2. If you do not see a rule that allows connections to port 3000, then your
   firewall is blocking access to that port.

To create a rule that allows connections to port 3000, follow these steps:

1. In the left pane of the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security
   console, expand Inbound Rules.
2. In the right pane, right-click New Rule and select Port.
3. In the Port Type dialog box, select TCP and enter 3000 in the
   Specific local ports box,Click Next
4. In the Action dialog box, select Allow the connection. Click Next.
5. In the Profile dialog box, select the profiles that you want to
   apply the rule to,Click Next.
6. In the Name dialog box, enter a name for the rule.
7. Click Finish.

I understand the question is for cloud service, but the above steps might help someone facing the same issue for on-prem servers